# MFC: SetMapMode(MM_ANISOTROPIC)

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc

I have a question about MM_ANISOTROPIC

The following code will scale my drawing to match window size

```
void CMapModeTestView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC) 
{
    CMapModeTestDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(&rect);

    pDC->SetMapMode (MM_ANISOTROPIC);
    pDC->SetWindowExt(1024, 768); 
    pDC->SetViewportExt(rect.Width(), rect.Height());

    /* This line of code draws a rectangle but will not increase memory */
    pDC->Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768);


    /* This line of code draws text but increases memory */
    pDC->DrawText(_("Test"), CRect(50, 50, 100, 100), DT_CENTER);
}
```

If I run this program and check Windows Task Manager (Windows 7), I see continuous increase in memory as I resize program's window by mouse.

I searched for any information related to `MM_ANISOTROPIC` mode, but could find only this [Bug](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/149289) which relates to memory leaks when we use create font in a device context that is set to `MM_ANISOTROPIC` mode.

NOTE: Program runs on VS C++ 6.0

Comment: You haven't shown any code here that's using any memory, so it's impossible to speculate about a memory leak. Does the leak go away when you switch to a different mode?

Comment: Yeap, It's strange. If I use other mode, memory does not increase. In other words, it's ok with any mode except MM_ANISOTROPIC and may be with MM_ISOTROPIC. Because when I run program (with MM_ISOTROPIC mode) on two different computer. One has memory leaks, and another has not.

Comment: Can you post the code which is handling the window resize message? If it is the same as what you have already posted, then post the entire function so that we can see what is being done to the `pDC`

Comment: It only leaks memory when use mouse to resize. In case of you double click on window bar to maximize, memory does not leak.